# Renaming shapefiles from Cyrillic symbols to Latin ones using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, unicode, transliteration

My goal is to rename shapefiles in 2 folders via transliteration using arcpy. That means that I want to replace Cyrillic (Russian) symbols with Latin ones. Here is my code, that doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

```
import arcpy

InWork =  ["C:\\Users\Vadim\Downloads\GML\esri", "C:\\Users\Vadim\Downloads\GML\stp"]

for ws in InWork:
    arcpy.env.workspace = ws
    datasets = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in datasets:
        newName = fc.replace(u"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыьэАБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭ",u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E")
        arcpy.Rename_management(fc, newName[:-4])
```

Comment: This appears to be more of a Python issue (relating to how `string.replace()` works) than a GIS-specific task.

Answer (score 3):

If you use string.replace here, you will have to run it separately for each character in your string which will be tedious and inefficient.

I think a better approach is to use a dictionary (which will allow for fast lookup) and a string builder (for fast construction).

See the answer from @Hans on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835637/net-string-replace-russian-to-english

Also this package is designed to do character to character translation so you might try it out first and see if you get the desired results: https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/